# MapReduceOptionsBuilder() couldnot be found. MongoDb join collections

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying join two mongoDB collections in my c# code. and trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022606/how-to-join-2-collections-using-mapreduce-in-c?answertab=active) example.

But my code give me error on following line. saying MapReduceOptionsBuilder couldnot be found.

```
var options = new  MapReduceOptionsBuilder();
options.SetOutput(MapReduceOutput.Inline);
options.SetOutput(MapReduceOutput.Reduce("result"));
var result = cLifeExpectancy.MapReduce(life_expect_map, r, options);
result = cEconomicAssistance.MapReduce(us_econ_map, r, options);
```

I have following Nuget install in my project:

1. MongoDB.Bson
2. MongoDB.Driver
3. MongoDB.Driver.core

following References added.

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Builders;
```

Can someone tell me what am I missing? or share some other example of joining MongoDB collection in C#.net. or alternative of MapReduceOptionsBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

probably because that class is obsolete. Unless you're using older version of the driver

http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/1.11/html/ebbdbd35-63b2-7656-aca9-8c13a8c57aa4.htm

below link has an example of how to using MapReduceOptions.

Hope this helps [MongoDB C# driver 2.0: How to get the result from MapReduceAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776621/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-2-0-how-to-get-the-result-from-mapreduceasync)

Comment: it still says "MapReduceOptionsBuilder" is absolut. use "MapReduceArgs" instead. how can i use MapReduceArgs to get the same results.

Comment: Added the link in the answer instead